# Prevent GCC array-bounds warning when accessing linker variable

Tags: c, gcc, linker

Given the following linker script extract:

```
.log_data :
  {
    PROVIDE(__start_log_section = .);
    KEEP(*(SORT(.log_section*)))
    PROVIDE(__stop_log_section = .);
  } > FLASH
```

And the following C code:

```
extern void *__start_log_section;
extern void *__stop_log_section;
...
uint16_t byteAtOffset3 = *((uint16_t *)&__start_log_section + 3);
```

I get the warning `array subscript 3 is outside array bounds of 'void[4]'...note: note: at offset 6 into object '__start_log_const_data' of size 4`. I can see why GCC is producing the error – I'm taking the reference to a variable (which is size 4 on a 32 bit processor), and then going beyond the bounds of the variable – but that's how linker variables work. Is there a way I can suppress these warnings/indicate to GCC that this is ok without having to use #pragma (which I can't use in macros)?

Comment: Why are you declaring `__start_log_section` to have type `void *`? Why not `extern unsigned char __start_log_section[];`. That is essentially what it is, an array of bytes in memory you want to access.

Comment: Also, why is the address converted to `uint16_t` and dereferenced but called `byteAtOffset3`? Are you trying to access a byte or 16 bits? If you want a byte, shouldn’t you convert to `unsigned char *`? If you want 16 bits, shouldn’t you call it `uint16AtOffset3`? Also, is that offset in elements of type `uint16_t`? So it is 6 bytes? You might want to be clear about that in comments and naming.

Comment: I'm not seeing the point of this linker game.  Why not use your linker script to define `byteAtOffset3` at whatever location you want it?  Or alternatively, why do any of this via a linker script at all?  But if you want to play this game anyway, then is this a one-off, or an example of a pattern you want to use multiple times?

Comment: @EricPostpischil `extern unsigned char __start_log_section[];` was the approach I ended up using. The code above was an abstract example, the types are different in my real project. I was also using uint8_t first, thus the use of "byte", but changes to uint16_t in constructing the example.

Answer (score 0):

The following variable definitions resolved the error:

```
extern unsigned char __start_log_section[];
extern unsigned char __stop_log_section[];
```